# Java JSON to object

Tags: java, json

I'm using Java to retrive some JSON from REST service. What I like to have is map JSON "node" to Java object.

The JSON is like this:

```
{  
   "token":{  
      "tokenType":"Bearer",
      "accessToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MTU0MDY0MjgsImlhdCI6MTUxNTQwNTUyOCwic3ViIjoiNWE1MzQwZDg4NmUxYTc2ZGU2MTY2NTQ2In0.7YjmghgAQLtyNaPuWDp9StQBJv79JQZD3G_XbKvYOaQ",
      "refreshToken":"5a5340d886e1a76de6166546.35e821dd2042efad2add8da80d6c765bded3ca37078415a4ebe46f9ba8da312a6d16cc05e91431bc",
      "expiresIn":"2018-01-08T10:13:48.261Z"
   },
   "user":{  
      "id":"5a5340d886e1a76de6166546",
      "email":"testingsest@gmail.com",
      "role":"user",
      "createdAt":"2018-01-08T09:58:48.153Z"
   }
}
```

Token.java is like:

```
public class Token {

    String tokenType;
    String accessToken;
    String refreshToken;
    long expiresIn;

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public String getRefreshToken() {
        return refreshToken;
    }

    public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    public long getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    public void setExpiresIn(long expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }


}
```

How to map "token" into Object using Jackson library (using ObjectMapper)?

(I know how to manully parse JSON and manually fill setters method in Token class)

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ but you need to learn to Google such things out.

Comment: The problem is that I have nested JSON and need only to fill Token object (without User datas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as following:

First, create a `User` class:

```
public class User {

    private String id;

    private String email;

    private String role;

    private String createdAt;

    //constructors and getters/setters
}
```

And create your wrapper class (here I named it `Session`):

```
public class Session {

    private Token token;

    private User user;

    //constructors and getters/setters
}
```

Then you can unmarchall your recieved object with Jackson as an instance of `Session`.

---- EDIT:

If you don't want to map the `User` inside your `Session`, just add the following annotation on `Session` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Session {

    private Token token;

    //constructors and getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Session session = mapper.readValue(response, Session.class);

Comment: Your welcome. I added a comment in my answer if you don't want to map the `user`.